# SQL Error (4145): An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where condition is expected, near '('

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

Using the below statement to check whether a field is null and if it is null then I need to show "Not Yet Approved" message. Otherwise I would like to get a concatenated result of some fields which is mentioned below.

```
select 
    iif(isnull(AppByENo1,'true'),'Not Yet Approved',AppByENo1+AppByDesg1+AppByDate1) as result
from myDB 
    where (E_No = '25')
```

But getting the above mentioned error while trying to run the sql query.

Please advice where I am making mistake and how to tackle this issue.

Comment: What is your E_No datatype..?

Comment: it's nvarchar(50)

Comment: `'true'` != `true`, but even if it were, there are no boolean literals in SQL Server since there's no user-exposed boolean data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
select 
iif(isnull(AppByENo1,'true') = 'true','Not Yet Approved',AppByENo1+AppByDesg1+AppByDate1) as result
from myDB 
where (E_No = '25')
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked nicely as per my expectation.  It considers single field for null operation so this will work faster (I hope).

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you have to use a sentinel value that will not appear naturally. If `AppByENo1` could actually be equal to `true` then it would be dealt with the same as if it were `null`. If you're going to go down the `iif` route, I'd strongly suggest just having `AppByENo1 is null` be the condition rather than doing fruity things with `isnull` and strings.

Answer (score 1):

Since concatenating null values yields null (providing you're leaving [appropiate settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-concat-null-yields-null-transact-sql) turned on, which you should), you can just use a simple [`coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) to replace the null if necessary:

```
select 
    COALESCE(AppByENo1+AppByDesg1+AppByDate1,'Not Yet Approved') as result
from myDB 
    where (E_No = '25')
```

If you insist on the `iif` approach, I'd favour:

```
iif(AppByENo1 is null,'Not Yet Approved',AppByENo1+AppByDesg1+AppByDate1)
```

E.g. an actual `null` test, rather than trying to identify a sentinel string that cannot appear naturally and performing a string comparison after `isnull`.

Comment: Nice thought by adding the 'Not Yet Approved' as the next field in COALESCE().  But I want to make it more speeder by comparing a single field.

Comment: @Sixthsense - really - this is the performance bottleneck in your application? I'd favour *straightforward*, readable code over "speeder" code that hasn't actually been measured for performance.

Comment: I agree with you.  Your suggested solution is very easy to handle and read.  But the query is going to run on 60 Million Data and it may grow in future to another 60 Million.  So I am trying to make it more speeder instead of giving importance to readability.

Comment: I just shown 3 fields concatenation here as an example.  But in real db concatenation occurs on 10x5.  (i.e.) each 10 fields with 5 COALESCE() functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use CASE Statement in SELECT clause instead of IFF :

```
  SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(AppByENo1,'true') = 'true' THEN 'Not Yet Approved'
     ELSE AppByENo1+AppByDesg1+AppByDate1 END as result
  FROM myDB WHERE E_No = '25'
```

Comment: Thanks for making me to know about Case Statement usage :)

Comment: @Sixthsense,Welcome.